# Text Is Not Centering

Tags: html, css

I have my `align="center"` and everything is all set, except the text will NOT center!  Can someone assist and show me what I did incorrectly in this?  And by the text I mean my header text the "Page Header" text listed in my code below.

```
<table style="text-align: left; width: 1000px; height: 251px; background-color: rgb(15, 100, 23);" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
<tbody>
    <tr style="font-family: Tahoma; color: white;" align="center">
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="1" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 100px; background-color: rgb(46, 480, 256);"><a name="ph2">Page Header</a>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 100px;">
            <br>
        <td style="vertical-align: top; font-family: Tahoma; background-color: white;"></td>
```

EDIT --- 
when i ran my syntax here for testing it was not showing as centered, increasing to 100% as suggested below is showing correctly.

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Its centered [example](http://codepen.io/mdan89/pen/PqxWVQ)

Comment: I think you are missing table cell closing tag in the second row in the first column of your table

Comment: also which browser are you opening the file with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was centered for me too, I changed your width to 100% so that it is centered to the screen.

https://jsfiddle.net/f9nngu82/

```
<table style="text-align: left; width: 100%; height: 251px; background-color: rgb(15, 100, 23);" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
<tbody>
    <tr style="font-family: Tahoma; color: white;" align="center">
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="1" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 100px; background-color: rgb(46, 480, 256);"><a name="ph2">Page Header</a>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 100px;">
            <br>
        <td style="vertical-align: top; font-family: Tahoma; background-color: white;"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try and use the center tag and put everything in between.Not the best way, but it works.
< center> < /center>